# Extract the values of a column and put them into an array

Tags: powershell

I want to find out how many java PIDs are running in order to stop them, put the values into an array, run it inside a loop and kill each process

Therefore  I use the command

```
$a=ps | Where-Object -Property ProcessName -EQ -Value 'Java'`
```

Which shows me the following result:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     **Id** ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    661      51   748504     421716  -282            **2008** java
    331      22   358464     135808  -525           **14060** java
```

But I am stuck regarding how to extract the Id column values, in order to loop them later

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: You can just `ps Java | Stop-Process` there is no need to store the PIDs in this case

Comment: And to answer the literal question as asked (as opposed to the problem you were trying to solve :-)), you can use “Member Access Enumeration (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2) - i.e. ```(ps Java).Id``` which will return an array containing the id of every item in the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) commented, you can directly pipe the output of `Get-Process` (alias `ps`) to `Stop-Process`:

```sh
ps Java | Stop-Process
```

In case you want to list the killed processes, you can use `-PassThru`:

```sh
ps Java | Stop-Process -PassThru
```

So in most cases you don't even need to write a loop.

If you still have a use case where you need to explicitly loop over the process IDs, you can do it as suggested by [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton), using [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2):

```sh
$proc = ps Java
foreach( $pid in $proc.Id ) {
    # do something with $pid
    "PID: $pid"
}

# ...or even shorter:
(ps Java).Id.ForEach{
    "PID: $_"
}
```